# IE Placeholder issue with password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am aware that this is a common issue but I haven't yet came across a solution which works or fits my problem.

The placeholders work with the JQuery I've used - as I've seen with many other people, the password field shows up as ********* but when I click on it the text changes to my placeholder "Type a password".

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    //IE 8 Placeholder 


(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(function () {
        $('[placeholder]')
            .focus(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() === input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('').removeClass('placeholder');
                }
            })
            .blur(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() === '' || input.val() === input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.addClass('placeholder').val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                }
            })
            .blur()
            .parents('form').submit(function () {
                $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (input.val() === input.attr('placeholder')) {
                        input.val('');
                    }
                });
            });
    });
})(jQuery);

// minified javascript
(function(j,p){j(function(){j("["+p+"]").focus(function(){var i=j(this);if(i.val()===i.attr(p)){i.val("").removeClass(p)}}).blur(function(){var i=j(this);if(i.val()===""||i.val()===i.attr(p)){i.addClass(p).val(c.attr(p))}}).blur().parents("form").submit(function(){j(this).find(p).each(function(){var i=j(this);if(i.val()===i.attr(p)){i.val("")}})})})})(jQuery,"placeholder");


    </script>
```

I'm only a beginner and I'm not good with JavaScript so could anyone tell me if they have came across this before and any potential fixes to the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/), but the phrase "Type a password" suggests that you are using it as one. Use a proper label. Make the placeholder be the helpful hint that it is supposed to be. Don't worry about people using prehistoric versions of IE not getting the hint. The label should be all they absolutely **need**.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the project I am working on requires it to mirror a sleek look of another application which uses placeholders and not labels - Which has a password field that works properly in IE